# How to avoid setting a fixed buffer size when using a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have this feature in my ASP.NET MVC intranet that displays the workload of employees in weekly ranges. This `WeeklyMonitoring` page has a stored procedure that selects the following information: `Company`, `Name`, `ExpectedWorkTime` and `RecordedTime` depending on the selected week.

Here is how I call this stored procedure and how I save the selected data:

```
 conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
 conn.Open();

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetWeeklyActivityByEmployee", conn);
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@startDate", wk1)); //wk1 is the starting week of the time range
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@endDate", wk2)); //wk2 is the ending week of the time range

 rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

 string[] tab_company = new string[9999];
 string[] tab_name = new string[9999];
 string[] tab_expectedtime = new string[9999];
 string[] tab_rectime = new string[9999];

 int counter;
 counter = 0;

 while (rdr.Read())
 {
     tab_company[counter] = rdr["Company"].ToString();
     tab_name[counter] = rdr["Name"].ToString();
     tab_expectedtime[counter] = rdr["Expected Time"].ToString();
     tab_rectime[counter] = rdr["Recorder Time"].ToString();

     counter++;
 }
```

Being new to all of these technologies (be it ASP.NET MVC or SQL Server 2008) I did not figure out a way to avoid setting a fixed buffer size for my `string[]`s.

Would such a thing be possible? How can I retrieve my data with buffer sizes that vary depending on the amount of data retrieved from my database?

Comment: you need to use executescalar for count but best you can use generic list.

Comment: Consider using a `class` (say `Workload`) that has four properties (`Company`, `Name`, `ExpectedTime` and `RecordedTime`). Then consider using something *other* than arrays for storing the results - say a `List<Workload>`.

Comment: The solution provided by Damien above is the best possible option but if you don't want to make a lot of changes, you can do like List<string> tab_company = new List<string>(); and than in the while loop, do like tab_company.Add(rdr["Company"]).ToString();

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll look into Damiens idea but I'll also take a look at yours. Both seem perfect but I'll certainly go for the most efficient one.